# export can't export variables permanently on Mac

Tags: macos, bash

I want to set a env variable globally, so I add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export MONGO_HOME=~/mongo
```

It works in this command console, but when I open another command console, it doesn't work; just after I type `source ~/.bashrc` it works, so I add this code to `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` also, but same result.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how can I save this variable permanently? I'm on Mac.

Comment: How did you open the terminal?

Comment: @cuonglm,right click command console icon,then click "new window",I also tried `command+N`,same result.

Comment: Strange, it should work. What `$SHELL` return?

Comment: @cuonglm,returns `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Are you aware that , by default,`.bashrc` is not executed by scripts?

Comment: @cdarke,sorry I didn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand why someone flag this question as "outoftopic-general computing hardware and software",but I must say please see the latter of the flag:**unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**,I think  the question have so much relations with programming that it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: What cdarke meant was that `~/.bashrc` is only sourced by _interactive_ (non-login) Bash instances ; since scripts run in _noninteractive_ shells, they do not source these files themselves; however, they do inherit environment variables from their parent process, so if the parent process is an interactive shell, then the script sees the same environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scott Crook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35054295/45375) provides an effective solution.

Here's some background:

- On OS X, all Bash instances created by `Terminal.app` are *login* shells (unlike the instances created by terminals on most Linux systems).
- Interactive Bash login shells, at the user level, source the *first* of the following files that exists: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`; as interactive *login* shells, however, they do *not* also source `~/.bashrc`.
- Thus, to ensure that `~/.bashrc` is loaded in *all* interactive shells, it should be sourced from `~/.bash_profile`, as [Scott Crook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35054295/45375) recommends.

Adding your `export` statements to `~/.bash_profile` *should* have taken effect in any shell tabs/windows opened thereafter.
To troubleshoot, simply add an `echo "Loading <filename>"` statement to the beginning of the initialization file(s) of interest.

Note that even though you say *globally*, the above only takes effect:

- for *interactive* shell instances (notably not for shells created by applications behind the scenes).
- for the current user

To have environment-variable definitions take effect for *all* users, place them in `/etc/profile`, but not that, again, this will only take effect for *interactive* shells.

Comment: but after  I move the export statements to `bash_profile` it still not work.

Comment: @FireSun: Have you tried adding an `echo` statement to `~/.bash_profile` to see if it is even loaded? Are you using the Mac's default terminal application, `Terminal.app`? How are you opening a new terminal window? You've already confirmed that Bash is your default shell, via `$SHELL`. At this point I suggest you ask a _new_ question and describe all troubleshooting steps you've tried and their outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The `.bash_profile` file in your home directory should contain the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Which does a quick check if your `~/.bashrc` file exists, and sources the file only if it exists. Ensure that bit of code is present, and then reopen your terminal application.  Your variable `MONGO_HOME` should then be present.

Comment: The shebang line is unnecessary and potentially confusing.  `.bash_profile` should not be executed by a subshell, ever, as that would defeat its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In macOS Catalina or newer, zsh is the default shell for new users. Here's how to permanently set environment variables for it.

**TL;DR add export line to bottom of `~/.zprofile`**

Start by opening `~/.zprofile` your editor. In this example, we'll use `vim`.

```
vim ~/.zprofile
```

In `vim`, hold the down arrow until you reach the bottom of the document.
Press `i` to enter insert mode, and type in your `export` line, i.e:

```
#.....
export JBOSS_HOME=/Applications/wildfly-27.0.1.Final
```

Afterwards, press `escape` to exit insert mode, type `:wq`, and restart your shell. The variable will be set.